# Generating an AST report from Java source code without actually running it

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

So I spend the whole day trying to figure out how to work with ANTLR. I have a bunch of Java source code files. My goal is to use ANTLR in order to create an AST for each one of those files. In the end, the AST will be converted to JSON so it will be easier to parse each one of them with a dynamic language like python. The conversion will use the solution in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116223/convert-antlr-parse-tree-to-json) (although if someone have a better solution I will be glad to hear). I have managed to run the basic example in the [getting-started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) page. Now I'm trying to figure out how to create an AST for one of my Java source code files. As it is said in the [getting-started](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md) page, I can use the [Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java) for that. I have downloaded `JavaParser.g4` and `JavaLexer.g4`. I tried to run:

```
java -Xmx500M -cp "/p/antlr-4.8-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool JavaParser.g4
```

But I get the error:

```
JavaParser.g4:32:21: cannot find tokens file ./JavaLexer.tokens
```

I guess I need to create that file somehow but I could not understand how, from the docs. So I tried to find that file in Github and I found it [here](https://github.com/urish/java-ast/tree/master/src/parser). I have downloaded it and it looked ok:

```
java -Xmx500M -cp "/p/antlr-4.8-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.Tool JavaParser.g4
javac JavaP*.java // Also tried javac Java*.java
java -Xmx500M -cp "/p/antlr-4.8-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig JavaParser r -gui
```

But I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class JavaParser                                                                                                                                            
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)                                                                                                                                                               
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:135)                                                                                                                                                        
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
```

Not sure what I do wrong or whether I'm doing the right thing in order to solve my problem.
All I want to do is to create an AST of the file `/tmp/file.java` and I'm not even sure where I should include it in the commands.
So my questions are:

1. How do I create an AST for the file `/tmp/file.java`?
2. Is it possible to create an AST file without actually writing Java code? I saw many places where they suggest to write Java code and compile it wtih Maven or some other tool. I prefer not to do it if possible, rather use the command-line option.
3. It's been a while since the JSON topic (mentioned above) was updated. Have something changed? Is it possible to create a JSON report without actually running Java?

As you can see I'm really confused so I appreciate any help!

**EDIT**: A small clarification - I don't need the AST image, rather to create a JSON report. If there is no easy way to do it, I'm sure that ANTLR has some raw file with that info that I could parse and convert it into JSON. Although, where is that raw data located?

Answer (score 0):

I hope your classpath is correct. It needs the current directory in addition to the ANTLR tool `jar`. So something like `.;C:\...\antlr.jar`. As for using ANTLR on the Java grammar, you can do this:

```sh
$ antlr4 JavaLexer.g4 JavaParser.g4
$ javac Java*.java
$ grun Java compilationUnit -tree -gui
```

`-gui` will pop a window which may take some time. Remember to send an `EOF` to the ANTLR runtime after you type something to `stdin`. (CTLR+Z on Windows, CTLR+D on Linux) Alternatively, you can input a file as an extra argument to `grun`.

From the two `.g4` files, I couldn't tell that the grammar name was `Java`. I just guessed it out based on the context. `compilationUnit` is the name of the first grammar rule all java files start with. This can be deduced by opening the `JavaParser.g4` and reading the first rule.

Here are the aliases I used on Git Bash.

```sh
$ alias
alias antlr4='java -Xmx500M org.antlr.v4.Tool'
alias grun='java -Xmx500M org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
```