# Simple Example of Modifying ANTLR4 Behaviour

Tags: java, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

We are using antlr4 to parse a purpose designed language. We have been able to create a grammar, and we are now using it to generate the diagrams we need.

Unfortunately, I need a bit more. I need to add line numbers to a homogeneous AST and get the results in a text file. I see a lot of questions/answers to this but since this is our first time adding to antlr, is there a simple, complete example of this ? We have both books but they assume a lot more familiarity with the process than we have.

Is there a source with a simple extension that we could build from ? I think we can complete it reasonably quickly, but we need a starter guide.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you question is exactly. ANTLR already provides you line numbers in the parse tree it generates (checkout the `start` and `stop` tokens of the `ParserRuleContext` class). If you create your own AST nodes from this parse tree, you can copy the line numbers to your own AST. And the problem description "get the results in a text file" is a bit vague: that could mean an awful lot of things.

Comment: My apologies. What I am looking for is more of a json or even a single line output. Instead of a graphical tree, something more like this where the output is to text. Crudely, something like: {"name": "Visibility and Comment Example",
   "model": {
      "id": "id.0",
   "line": linestart,
   "col": colstart,
   "lineend":lineend,
   "colend": colend,
      "codeElement": {
         "id": "id.1",
    "line": linestart,
    "col": colstart,
    "lineend":lineend,
    "colend": colend,
         "codeElement": [
     Where the level in json determines the parent child.

Comment: OK, then checkout the `start` and `stop` of the `ParserRuleContext` class, it contains all that. Also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116223/convert-antlr-parse-tree-to-json