# Parse C++ with Python

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

Im trying to parse cpp using python. I generated the parser with ANTLR for python and now I want to visit the tree and gather some information.

- Is there anyway to dump the ANTLR tree as AST in JSON format?
- I was trying to trace the function calls I was expecting something like CallExpr but I couldn't find anything in generated parser files.

This is the grammar file im using https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/CPP14.g4

I tried the following command to get the CPP parser, 
java -jar antlr-4.8-complete.jar -Dlanguage=Python3 ./CPP14.g4 -visitor

and this is the very basic code i have

```
import sys
import os
from antlr4 import *
from CPP14Lexer import *
from CPP14Parser import *
from CPP14Visitor import *



class TREEVisitor(CPP14Visitor):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def visitExpressionstatement(self, ctx):
        print(ctx.getText())
        return self.visitChildren(ctx)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    dtype = ""
    input_stream = FileStream(sys.argv[1])
    cpplex = CPP14Lexer(input_stream)
    commtokstream = CommonTokenStream(cpplex)
    cpparser = CPP14Parser(commtokstream)
    print("parse errors: {}".format(cpparser._syntaxErrors))

    tree = cpparser.translationunit()

    tv = TREEVisitor()
    tv.visit(tree)
```

and the input file im trying to parse,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int foo(int i, int i2)
{
    return i * i2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    foo(1, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a link to the grammar you're using? Can you also update your question and post the code you're using to parse the CPP source file? (as well as the contents of this source file)

Comment: In the grammar, I don't see a rule called `CallExpr`: why are you expecting it? What is the input you're parsing?

Comment: The question is how can I visit the function calls like foo(1, 2, 3); I thought maybe that is defined under another name in that grammar file!

Comment: remove  `def __init__(self):
        pass`

Comment: @eyllanesc that might be good advice, but it has nothing to do with the problem at hand. And when giving advice, it would be nice to explain why, or provide a link that explains this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls are recognised by the `postfixexpression` rule:

```
postfixexpression
   : primaryexpression
   | postfixexpression '[' expression ']'
   | postfixexpression '[' bracedinitlist ']'
   | postfixexpression '(' expressionlist? ')'   // <---- this alternative!
   | simpletypespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'
   | typenamespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'
   | simpletypespecifier bracedinitlist
   | typenamespecifier bracedinitlist
   | postfixexpression '.' Template? idexpression
   | postfixexpression '->' Template? idexpression
   | postfixexpression '.' pseudodestructorname
   | postfixexpression '->' pseudodestructorname
   | postfixexpression '++'
   | postfixexpression '--'
   | Dynamic_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'
   | Static_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'
   | Reinterpret_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'
   | Const_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'
   | typeidofthetypeid '(' expression ')'
   | typeidofthetypeid '(' thetypeid ')'
   ;
```

So if you add this to your visitor:

```py
def visitPostfixexpression(self, ctx:CPP14Parser.PostfixexpressionContext):
    print(ctx.getText())
    return self.visitChildren(ctx)
```

It will get printed. Note that it will now print a lot more than function calls, since it matches much more than that. You could [label the alternatives](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels):

```
postfixexpression
   : primaryexpression                                     #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '[' expression ']'                  #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '[' bracedinitlist ']'              #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '(' expressionlist? ')'             #functionCallPostfixexpression
   | simpletypespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'           #otherPostfixexpression
   | typenamespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'             #otherPostfixexpression
   | simpletypespecifier bracedinitlist                    #otherPostfixexpression
   | typenamespecifier bracedinitlist                      #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '.' Template? idexpression          #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '->' Template? idexpression         #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '.' pseudodestructorname            #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '->' pseudodestructorname           #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '++'                                #otherPostfixexpression
   | postfixexpression '--'                                #otherPostfixexpression
   | Dynamic_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'     #otherPostfixexpression
   | Static_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'      #otherPostfixexpression
   | Reinterpret_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')' #otherPostfixexpression
   | Const_cast '<' thetypeid '>' '(' expression ')'       #otherPostfixexpression
   | typeidofthetypeid '(' expression ')'                  #otherPostfixexpression
   | typeidofthetypeid '(' thetypeid ')'                   #otherPostfixexpression
   ;
```

and you can then do:

```py
def visitFunctionCallPostfixexpression(self, ctx:CPP14Parser.FunctionCallPostfixexpressionContext):
    print(ctx.getText())
    return self.visitChildren(ctx)
```

and then only `foo(1,3)` gets printed (note that you might want to label more rules as `functionCallPostfixexpression` inside the `postfixexpression` rule).

> Is there anyway to dump the ANTLR tree as AST in JSON format?

No.

But you could easily create something yourself of course: the objects returned by each parser rule, like `translationunit`, contains the entire tree. A quick and dirty example:

```py
import antlr4
from antlr4.tree.Tree import TerminalNodeImpl
import json

# import CPP14Lexer, CPP14Parser, ...


def to_dict(root):
    obj = {}
    _fill(obj, root)
    return obj


def _fill(obj, node):

    if isinstance(node, TerminalNodeImpl):
        obj["type"] = node.symbol.type
        obj["text"] = node.getText()
        return

    class_name = type(node).__name__.replace('Context', '')
    rule_name = '{}{}'.format(class_name[0].lower(), class_name[1:])
    arr = []
    obj[rule_name] = arr

    for child_node in node.children:
        child_obj = {}
        arr.append(child_obj)
        _fill(child_obj, child_node)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = """
        #include <iostream>

        using namespace std;

        int foo(int i, int i2)
        {
            return i * i2;
        }

        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            cout << "test" << endl;
            foo(1, 3);
            return 0;
        }
        """
    lexer = CPP14Lexer(antlr4.InputStream(source))
    parser = CPP14Parser(antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    tree = parser.translationunit()
    tree_dict = to_dict(tree)
    json_str = json.dumps(tree_dict, indent=2)
    print(json_str)
```

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116223/convert-antlr-parse-tree-to-json , I wonder if that can be used for CPP?

Comment: Sure, you,ll just have ro port the Java code to Python

Comment: @Alex I added a quick example snippet of how you could go about it

Comment: Is there any doc for explaining all those terms in the output tree?
When the function foo is called in seems its under 
"unaryexpression": [...] and then its argument again under "unaryexpression", is that normal?

Im not sure how i must interpret the output!

I mean that is only a function call but it is under "expressionstatement", "assignmentexpression", "conditionalexpression", "logicalorexpression" and many others... 
That looks weird to me!

Comment: Yes, that's normal. The parser starts with `translationunit`, if you follow the path it makes to eventually come to your function call.

Comment: As you said visitPostfixexpression show many other stuff in the output, for example stuff like "i =10;" and i think that is because of the ": primaryexpression" in grammars for "postfixexpression", I tried to remove it or even define another one without Literals in it but no luck!
How can I only get function calls and their arguments, how does `ctx` look like? how can i get the function name and their argument?

Comment: I don’t understand. I showed how to use visitFunctionCallPostfixexpression, which should work for you, right?

Comment: Yep, you answer were perfect I couldn't understand it.
My second question was How from inside visitFunctionCallPostfixexpression I can get function args?

I also implemented visitAssignmentexpression in my visitor but again I got much more than i wanted, i was expecting to get stuff like i = 10; etc.. but it return even the function calls.

Comment: A function has an optional `expressionlist`, and an `expressionlist` has a `initializerlist`, etc. So from the function context, you can do it like this: `ctx.expressionlist().initializerlist()...`. Note that since `expressionlist` is optional, `ctx.expressionlist()` might be `None`, so perform the needed checks yourself.

Comment: Or for `visitInitdeclarator` in the CPP code below,
```
    int i;
    int b, c;
    int d;
    i = 10;
    b = i;
    c = b;
    d += c;
    std::string str = "TEST";
    ping(argv[1]);
    Person *p = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();
```
I get he following output,
```
i
b
c
d
str="TEST"
p2=newPerson()
```
I cannot understand that output, i get `p2=newPerson()` and `str="TEST"` but not `b = i;` or `i =10;`.

Comment: Feel free to create a new question: these comment boxes are not suited for Q&A's.

Comment: Will do, I really appreciate your answers. Thank you Bart.